# Rails messaging one to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, messaging

Want to create real time direct messaging with user to user association, Though cant see exactly how to create this.

Example: User1 clicks the image of User2 from their contacts list, User1 creates a message and it sends to User2. User2 can see the message and replies back (like instant messaging) and both users see the same messages.

The message would have a title, image and body (each being available but not mandatory) The old messages and new message ability would be on the same page with old messages above the new message ability.

There is also the idea of how the messages are represented when reaching a user, if they are in conversation the messages appear in real time, if not in conversation then the contacts image would appear on the conversation page. Where you click a user to see the conversation.

I think part of the trouble is how do you identify the second user. Thinking along the below lines:

model User:

```
has_many :conversations
has_many :messages through => conversations
```

model Conversation:

```
has_many :messages
has_many :users
```

model Message:

```
belongs_to :users through => conversations
has_many :conversations
```

The tables would be along the line of:

message:

```
body
title
image
conversation_id
```

conversation:

```
message_id
user_id
```

user:

```
id
```

Any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

user.rb:

```
has_many :messages
has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
# id
```

message.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :conversation
# body
# title
# image
# conversation_id
# user_id
```

conversation.rb

```
has_many :messages
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
# id
```

conversations_users.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :conversation
# conversation_id
# user_id
```

Note: With this structure can also have more than two members.

Hope this help. :)

Comment: hi @Nhã Huỳnh tks for the revert. How does this select user1 and user2? At the moment if user1 creates the message isn't that only linked to him by user_id?

Comment: Hi @blastoff, when user1 create message, it is inside the conversation between them (the users). Just conversation.messages to get all messages. Including the new one. P/s: the user_id of message in this case just show us who is the owner of the message. Conversation is the main model. Hope this help. :)

Comment: okay. so the # id under the User and Conversation is their own id? i.e the id which is auto generated for all tables. Also does it really need 4 different models to do this, not that i know but would have thought it could be done with 3 at most.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We don't have to create conversations_users.rb. But it is required "conversations_users" in your database. :)

Comment: ok thanks. Are you able to show the necessary Views and Controllers? From last night till now still cant visually see how this fits together and don't see the logic...its a learning curve!